# bootmgr missing after resuming from hybernation (win7 x64)

Tags: windows-7, boot

I've got this issue only two times by now and after ctrl+alt+del it boots perfectly. But just to be sure - is my hard drive going to fail or am I being paranoid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be an issue where the computer is trying to boot from a CD/DVD drive, a USB Flash Drive, or a second hard drive. You can check the BIOS to make sure the boot order is setup correctly, but often it is just an issue with a USB drive attached when booting the computer.